# How to delete the item in Qt promote selection

Tags: qt, qwidget

[image: This is the promoted widgets form]

Actually I have two choices but the upper one (haha.h) is does not exist, and I can't find the way to delete it. I am beginner in Qt, so someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it manually, just open the MainWindow.ui with an editor and remove the xml entry of your promoted class. You will find something like this:

```
<customwidget>
   <class>haha</class>
   <extends>QLabel</extends>
   <header>haha.h</header>
   <container>0</container>
</customwidget>
```

Check the counter, if it higher than 0, then you have to demote all the promoted widgets. Another way its to try to promote a simple QWidget an then remove it from the Qt Creator menu,

Answer (score 6):

Very simple:

1. Select hana: The '-' sign on bottom-right will become RED.
2. Press on the RED '-'.

Good luck

Comment: The Red minus '-' sign is only available if you've previously demoted from that widget (before entering into the Promote Widgets dialog)